# JMeter CLI mode execution not stopping

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter so bear with me..

I have a setup of thread group with single user, within that thread group I have the following parameter setup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SanlI.png)

I run this in GUI mode i got the correct summary report as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDMiL.png)

But when I execute this in CLI with command (jmeter -n -t(abc.jmx) -l(xyz.csv) -e -o (report.html)), The  execution is run continuously as below by adding the previous one. And the request count is also not correct. I have only 3 request in the test plan.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbhiF.png)

The generated log report is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG5VI.png)

Any idea on this?

I am expecting a proper summary report without any redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

It's known [JMeter issue 6008](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/6008), there are following workarounds/fixes:

1. Upgrade to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) which contains the fix. Moreover [it's recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Insert  `<boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>` line into the [.jmx script directly](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
3. Downgrade to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)
4. Switch to another Thread Group like [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group)